# Combine 2 char cell arrays in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have the following two cell arrays:

```
Array1 = 
    '016597'
    '133767'
    '029015'
    '012252'
    '162733'
    '029830'
```

and

```
Array2 = 
    '01'
    '01'
    '01'
    '01'
    '01'
    '01'
```

Is there a way to combine these two to look like the following without the use of a loop? (`Array3` is just each row of `Array1` and `Array2` combined together)

```
Array3 = 
    '01659701'
    '13376701'
    '02901501'
    '01225201'
    '16273301'
    '02983001'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following would work:

```
cell2mat([Array1,Array2])
```

However this presumes that the length of each element of `Array1` will always be the same.

EDIT:

Actually, the following is a much cleaner and simpler way of doing it:

```
strcat(Array1,Array2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate Array1 and Array2 and store them in Array3
like this. you can use loop to concatenate all elements
       str = strcat('Good', 'morning')